# regular expression to extract middle section of string

Tags: regex

What could be the regex to extract 58392 from this example.

the number between the colon and hash would be variable length

```
sip:58392#7638500@10.10.10.10
```

I tried conbinations of like this but no luck `sip:(.*?)#/\1/`

Comment: What programming language/regex flavor? How exactly are you trying to use that pattern?

Answer (score 9):

try this expression,

```
(?<=:).*?(?=#)
```

See [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Width Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: Lose the unnecessary brackets around `.*?`

Comment: @Bohemian yeah, just for clarity, anyway, is there any performance difference of adding `()` on it?

Comment: @pete i think you'll find it *does* work - you need to extract `\0` (the entire match) not `\1` (the first group) because there *is* no first group with my suggestion

Comment: @JW. There would be a tiny performance gain because it doesn't need to create a group, but importantly it makes the regex simpler, and less code is good, especially where regex us concerned, because its practically write-only at the best of times

Answer (score 1):

here is a PHP example:

```
<?php

$string = 'sip:58392#7638500@10.10.10.10';
$pattern = '/^sip:([0-9]+)#/';
preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
echo "the number is : ", $matches[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2.7.3:

```
>>> import re
>>> r = r"sip:(.*?)#"
>>> s = "sip:58392#7638500@10.10.10.10"
>>> re.findall(r,s)
['58392']
```

...it works.

I don't get what the `/\1/` at the end of your regex is for - probably something for the specific flavour of regex you're using, but I suspect that's the problem.

Comment: Looks like a backreference inside a replacement - find this pattern, and replace with just the part between the parentheses

Answer (score 0):

The following will match **sip:58392#** and then by any split string method, I think that you are able to remove sip: and #.

```
sip:.*?\#
```